# 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Null>?'

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error while running a `getDocuments(source: Source.server)`. I'm not sure what the error is pointing to or what `Future<null>?` is.

cloud_firestore: 0.12.10+2

```
E/flutter (12116): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Null>?'
E/flutter (12116): #0      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:159:7)
E/flutter (12116): #1      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:694:47)
E/flutter (12116): #2      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:715:24)
E/flutter (12116): #3      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter (12116): #4      Future.timeout.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:780:16)
E/flutter (12116): #5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (12116): #6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (12116): #7      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
E/flutter (12116): #8      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
E/flutter (12116): #9      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
E/flutter (12116): #10     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
E/flutter (12116): #11     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:36:15)
E/flutter (12116): #12     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:298:13)
E/flutter (12116): #13     Query.getDocuments (package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart)
E/flutter (12116): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12116): #14     _OrderCardCheckableListState._retrieveInitialTenOrders (package:lightweight_pos/inventory_management_workflow/settlement_management/input_new_settlement_form/add_supplier_faktur_sub_route.dart:65:10)
E/flutter (12116): #15     _OrderCardCheckableListState.initState (package:lightweight_pos/inventory_management_workflow/settlement_management/input_new_settlement_form/add_supplier_faktur_sub_route.dart:143:5)
E/flutter (12116): #16     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4640:58)
E/flutter (12116): #17     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (12116): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (12116): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (12116): #20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (12116): #21     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (12116): #22     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (12116): #23     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (12116): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (12116): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (12116): #26     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (12116): #27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (12116): #28     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (12116): #29     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (12116): #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (12116): #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (12116): #32     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (12116): #33     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (12116): #34     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (12116): #35     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (12116): #36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (12116): #37     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5947:32)
E/flutter (12116): #38     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (12116): #39     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (12116): #40     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (12116): #41     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter (12116): #42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (12116): #43     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (12116): #44     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:11)
E/flutter (12116): #45
```

```
await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Suppliers')
        .where('SupplierID',
            isEqualTo: DataCenter.currentInputNewSettlementPageData.supplierID)
        .limit(10)
        .getDocuments(source: Source.server)
        .timeout(MyApp.systemTimeout)
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.documents == null || snapshot.documents.length == 0) noDocuments = true;
      _lastDocument = snapshot.documents.last;
      for (DocumentSnapshot doc in snapshot.documents) {
        _listOfSettleFakturData.add({
          'ReferenceNumber': doc['ReferenceNumber'],
          'FakturNumber': doc['FakturNumber'],
          'UnpaidAmount': doc['UnpaidAmount'],
          'UploadTime': doc['UploadTime'],
          'PaymentAmount': 1,
          'NewUnpaidAmount': doc['UnpaidAmount']
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to come from the fact that I was trying to access a non-existent field in the document. This happened since I was trying to access the wrong collection.

Supplier (for each document the field was as follows):

1. SupplierName

Restocks (the collection I intend to access, for each document the fields were as follows):

1. SupplierID (the intended field)
2. ...
3. ...
4. ...
5. ...
   .
   .
   .
   more fields

As far as I can understand, this was the problem, if anyone knows that I'm wrong please correct, I would like to know the proper cause so I can avoid it the next time.

Comment: For questions or concerns pertaining to your implementation with Flutter, I would like to direct you to the [Flutter Community page](https://flutter.dev/community). As they would be better suited in providing answers to your Flutter inquiries.

Comment: Does Flutter have an entire community by itself independent of stack overflow or you just meant adding the flutter tag so it comes up under the tag/topic?